# How to write a VB.Net Lambda expression

Tags: vb.net, linq, lambda

I am working on a VB.net project now. I am new to VB.Net LINQ and would like to know the Lambda equivalent of

```
var _new = orders.Select(x => x.items > 0);
```

in VB.Net.

Someone please suggest!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531253.aspx

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384991.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 116, accepted):

The lambda syntax isn't that much different than creating a regular delegate.

If creating a lambda which has a return value, use `Function`.  Otherwise if you're creating one that doesn't, use `Sub`.

```
Dim _new = orders.Select(Function(x) x.Items > 0)

Dim action As Action(Of Item) = Sub(x) Console.WriteLine(x.Items)
```

Comment: It looks different from a standard delegate, since in this case there is no `return` statement, and the value returned is the value of the expression in the body of the delegate.

Comment: I had always thought that the delegate in VB.net had an optional `Return` statement.