# vb.net equivalent to Bindings.Update()? (from c#)

Tags: c#, vb.net, binding, uwp

I'm currently learning UWP on the Microsoft Virtual Academy. Right now I'm on a challenge regarding adaptivity / binding. The course is taught in C# so I have to translate the C# code to vb.net, since this is the language I learned earlier. Not a huge deal until now:

When creating a UserControl that is to be put into a GridView, I am asked to put this line of Code after InitializeComponent().

```
this.DataContextChanged += (s, e) => Bindings.Update();
```

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to translate this expression into Visual Basic. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The solution Code can be found at 2:42 [here](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/windows-10-development-for-absolute-beginners-14541?l=XyVTDtCrB_7805244527).

The challange video can be found [here](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/windows-10-development-for-absolute-beginners-14541?l=DtFgZkCrB_7405244527).

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317333/how-to-write-a-vb-net-lambda-expression) is how you write an expression in VB.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
AddHandler Me.DataContextChanged, Sub(ss As FrameworkElement, ee As DataContextChangedEventArgs)
                                      Bindings.Update()
                                  End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your hint. Right now, though, i get: "'Bindings' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to ist protection Level.".

Comment: VB also lets you omit the lambda parameter types if you wish: e.g., Sub(s, e) Bindings.Update()

Comment: @Cineas: Actually the Bindings object should be created automatically for you if you actually use the {x:Bind} markup extension in your XAML view. You need to add the XAML markup in NewsItemsControl.xaml before you can call Bindings.Update().

Comment: Thanks for your help so far! Unfortunately, it did not create the the Bindings object. I have multiple {x:Bind}s in my NewsItemsControl.xaml. Im currently trying to reproduce the error in a new project.

Comment: Try to build the project and then add the call to the Bindings.Update method. It certainly works for me.

Comment: Allright! I got Bindings.Update() now! Thanks a lot! Still don't know how i would raise the DataContextChanged Event, tho. Does AddHandler do that? Cuz my UserControl still doesn't show up in the GridView. :(